# Flexbox: Last item is not on the right side

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to align the last item on the right side. I tried that with `margin-left: auto`.It should look exactly like the output on the jsfiddle. I use the same code in Visual Studio Code. However, when I look at the output in the browser (Firefox, Chrome, Edge), the item is not on the right side, although I am using the same code. What can be the error?
https://jsfiddle.net/mp7xsbzt/1/

[How it looks on the Firefox Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBEY5.png)

So the problem is that it is showing incorrectly in the browser even though it is showing correctly in the jsfiddle. I used the same code on both.

Comment: Kindly post your code. I copied the code from the jsfiddle shared, and it produces the correct output on both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If I remove the integration of Bootstrap, then it works as it should. So, the integration of Bootstrap caused the problem. Now I know the problem, but not how to fix it? After all, I need Bootstrap for the project.

```
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<script src="src/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="src/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the following styles:

```css
.item-right-justified {
  text-align: right;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

How it looks in firefox (now):
[image: Firefox]
You can view the new page [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamtheanonymouskoder/x89tLcu0/).